# Email search not finding certain emails

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

We had some email accounts under the domain @domain.com. An Exchange 2010 server was hosting these emails.

We then purchased a @domain.solutions custom domain and changed the primary email address to this for all users. We have kept the @domain.com as another SMTP email address.

Now, when we search for an email that is sent to the @domain.com, the search results return nothing.

We are using Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013.

Any idas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using the Mail search in Outlook here? Can the emails be found when you search for them in OWA? Do all users experience this problem?

Comment: Just waiting on feedback from other users. However 1 user the search works in OWA.

Comment: I can't really think of a reason why this is happening, but you may try to rebuild the search index of outlook. You can try for one user first. But if it works in OWA then it's usually some kind of client site issue, as OWA uses the data directly from exchange.

Comment: It is just the one user.

Comment: I am going to rebuild the search index and see what happens

Comment: Any progress in this issue?